# __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'password' django

Tags: python, ajax, django

I am using ajax calls in my program. I am getting errors like:

```
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'password'
```

I have following in model:

```
class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 20 )
    password = models.CharField(max_length = 100 )
    email = models.CharField( max_length = 10 )


class StudentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Student
        fields = '__all__
```

Now, the following is my template:

```
`<form id = "post_submit" action="{% url "apply" %}" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {% for field in form %}
            <p>{{field.label}} : {{field}}</p>
        {% endfor %}

        <p><input type="submit" name="Submit"></p>
    </form>
    <p id="click_option">Click here.</p>
```

Ajax calls are made using:

```
    $.ajax({


// using this for csrf handling




        // alert(" i am in ajax");
        // console.log(" iam ");
        url : "/apply/",
        type : "POST",
        data : 
        {
            csrfmiddlewaretoken:document.getElementsByName('csrfmiddlewaretoken')[0].value,
            name : $('#id_name').val(),
            email : $('#id_email').val(),
            password : $('#id_password').val(),
        },
        success: function(json) {
            alert("Congratulations! You scored: " + json['status']);

        },

        // error




    })


});
```

the view in backend is:
        def apply(request):

```
if request.method == 'POST':
            name = request.POST.get('name')
            email = request.POST.get('email')
            password = request.POST.get('password')

            student = StudentForm(name = name, email = email, password = password)
            student.save()

            data = {"status" : "success"}
            return JsonResponse(data)
        else:
            data = {"status" : "failure"}

            return JsonResponse(data)
```

Comment: You're calling the constructor of StudentForm which is not defined. The right way can be to create the object and then to assign values

Comment: ok, I got the issue. But why there is type error for `password` only? Why not for all values?

Comment: The `TypeError` only displays one field name at a time. If you changed it to `student = StudentForm(name = name, email = email)`, then you would get the same error for one of the other fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to manually fetch the values out of the POST data, the form takes care of that for you.

After checking if the form is valid, you can call `save()` to save the model instance.

```
form = StudentForm(request.POST)
if form.is_valid()
    student = form.save()
```

Finally, your `Student` model is storing a `password` in a `CharField`. It is insecure to store passwords in plain text. [Django's authentication system](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/) takes care of hashing passwords for you. Use it.

Comment: upvoted for the suggestion about the django's authentication system. Thank you very much.